# Listbox excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, validation, combobox, userform

I have two columns a sheet. 'Year' and 'Make'. I am trying to design a userform with two combobox for year and make. Every time I run the macro, I want the combobox 'year' to have one instance of every year from the 'year' column. say ther are 10 instances of 2014, 20 instances of 2015 and 30 od 2016. I need to have one instance of all three years. The number of unique years may vary. Is there a way I could do this?

If I use data validation, I get all thee instances. I just want it to appear once. Please help me out. Either data validation or the combobox method is fine for me. I just need to have a place where we can select one 'year' from the available years.

Comment: `I just need to have a place where we can select one 'year' from the available years` This is anywhere in the worksheet?

Comment: I have a 'home' sheet and 'data' sheet. The 'data' sheet has the 'model', 'year' and 'issues'. Home sheet should have a listbox where I can select the model and year so that I can make a chart that shows the number of issues for that particular selection.

Comment: Wouldn't a pivot table do using *Report Filter*?

Comment: Yes. But my boss wants it this way. I am breaking my head to do this. For now, I am copying the entire column to the home sheet, removing duplicates, using this as range for data validation and then deleting that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my idea of using a *Pivot Table*.
Select your *Year* column and make a table out of it.
 
Then summarize it using *Pivot Table*. Place it in *Report Filter Field* and you have your dropdown.

[image]

Another none VBA way is to use a helper column where it only outputs the unique values as discussed [HERE](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/04/14/create-a-unique-alphabetically-sorted-list-extracted-from-a-column/).

Using this formula: (credit's to Oscar)

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Year],MATCH(MIN(IF(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,Table1[Year])=0,1,MAX((COUNTIF(Table1[Year],"<"&Table1[Year])+1)*2))*(COUNTIF(Table1[Year],"<"&Table1[Year])+1)),COUNTIF(Table1[Year],"<"&Table1[Year])+1,0)),"")`

And entering it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
Take note that we used the table we just created.

[image]

After that, create a named range out of it.

[image]

And finally, you create the validation:

[image]

If you still need VBA, yes it can be done in various ways.
But before that, gauge if any of the two ways above will work for you. HTH.

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me do this and ask my boss if it suffices.